# al darle clic en un boton dentro de un while, solo me arroja datos del primer recorrido y de los siguientes no

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy haciendo un catalogo de productos, los muestro con un while y dentro están los botones de agregar al carrito. cuando doy clic en agregar al carrito en el primer producto lo agrega sin problemas, pero ya los demás no los detecta.
Creo suponer que el problema es por el boton pero no se como resolverlo, ojala me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería mucho.

Mi página donde muestro los productos:

```
<header class="ContenidoInicioCliente">
        <h1>PRODUCTOS</h1>
        <div id="Productos"></div>
        <?php
            include_once("../Consultas/Conexion.php");
            $consultaProductos = "SELECT * FROM prenda p JOIN tipprenda t ON p.IdTipoPrenda=t.IdTipoPrenda JOIN marca m ON p.IdMarca=m.IdMarca JOIN talla tl ON p.IdTalla=tl.IdTalla JOIN almacen a ON p.IdAlmacen=a.IdAlmacen JOIN proveedor pv ON p.IdProveedor=pv.IdProveedor";
            $resultado2 = mysqli_query($cn, $consultaProductos);
                while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2)) {
        ?>
                    <div id='ContenedorPincipalProd' name='ContenedorPincipalProd' class='ContenedorPincipalProd'>
                        <div id='ContenedorImag' name='ContenedorImag' class='ContenedorImag'>
                            <a href='../Consultas/.php' ><img id='ImagenProducto' name='ImagenProducto' src=<?php echo "../".$fila['RutaImagen']; ?>></a>
                        </div>
                        <div id='ContenedorNombres' name='ContenedorNombres' class='ContenedorNombres'>
                            <label id='textLabel1' name='textLabel1' class='textLabel'><?php echo $fila['NomPrenda']; ?></label>
                            <label id='textLabel4' name='textLabel4' class='textLabel'>Disp: <?php echo $fila['Cantidad']; ?></label>
                            <label id='textLabel2' name='textLabel2' class='textLabel'>Talla: <?php echo $fila['NomTalla']; ?></label>
                            <label id='textLabel3' name='textLabel3' class='textLabel'>Precio: <?php echo number_format($fila['Precio'], 2, '.', ','); ?></label>
                        </div>
                        <div id='ContenedorBotones' name='ContenedorBotones' class='ContenedorBotones'>
                            <input type="text" id="txtAgregarCarId" value="<?php echo $fila['IdPrenda']; ?>" hidden="true">
                            <button type="submit" id="btnCarrito" name='btnCarrito' class="btnCarrito">Agregar al carrito</button>
                            <button type="submit" id='btnMeGusta' name='btnMeGusta' class="btnMeGusta"></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <?php
                }
        ?>
    </header>
```

Aquí mando el id producto a php para almacenar o actualizar e la base de datos:

```
document.getElementById('btnCarrito').addEventListener("click", function(){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var parametros = "txtAgregarCarId=" + document.getElementById('txtAgregarCarId').value;
var url = "../Consultas/VMostrarProductosClientes.php";

xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(parametros);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
    {
        document.getElementById("Productos").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
} 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En cada ciclo while estas repitiendo **id** y eso perjudica al método **getElementById** porque solo capta el primero que encuentra, y no el que tu quieres que lo haga.

La solución pasa o bien por poner ids únicos en cada ciclo, o bien usar clases y delegación de eventos.

Esta respuesta se basa en las clases y la delegación de eventos.

Pasos a realizar para arreglar el problema:

1. Vamos a encerrar en un nuevo **div** todo el contenido del **while** agregando un `<div id="padre">` de este modo:

```
<div id="Productos"></div>
<div id="padre">
<?php
            include_once("../Consultas/Conexion.php");
            $consultaProductos = "etc...
```

y lo vamos a cerrar al salir del **while** así:

```
<?php
                }
        ?>
</div>
    </header>
```

2. Vamos a añadir unas cuantas clases y borrar los id que se repiten en cada ciclo:

```
<div name='ContenedorPincipalProd' class='ContenedorPincipalProd'>
                        <div name='ContenedorImag' class='ContenedorImag'>
                            <a href='../Consultas/.php' ><img class='ImagenProducto' name='ImagenProducto' src=<?php echo "../".$fila['RutaImagen']; ?>></a>
                        </div>
                        <div name='ContenedorNombres' class='ContenedorNombres'>
                            <label name='textLabel1' class='textLabel textLabel1'><?php echo $fila['NomPrenda']; ?></label>
                            <label name='textLabel4' class='textLabel textLabel4'>Disp: <?php echo $fila['Cantidad']; ?></label>
                            <label name='textLabel2' class='textLabel textLabel2'>Talla: <?php echo $fila['NomTalla']; ?></label>
                            <label name='textLabel3' class='textLabel textLabel3'>Precio: <?php echo number_format($fila['Precio'], 2, '.', ','); ?></label>
                        </div>
                        <div name='ContenedorBotones' class='ContenedorBotones'>
                            <input type="text" class="txtAgregarCarId" value="<?php echo $fila['IdPrenda']; ?>" hidden="true">
                            <button type="submit" name='btnCarrito' class="btnCarrito" value="<?php echo $fila['IdPrenda']; ?>">Agregar al carrito</button>
                            <button type="submit" name='btnMeGusta' class="btnMeGusta"></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Si te fijas, he quitado todos los id y los he puesto en sus clases, si no estaban.
Otro cambio importante es que he agregado un `value="<?php echo $fila['IdPrenda']; ?>"` en el botón de la clase **btnCarrito** que nos va a facilitar después su uso.

**Atención:** Tienes un campo escondido que diria que le falta un **name=** que es este (o bien ya no lo necesitas para nada):

```
<input type="text" class="txtAgregarCarId" value="<?php echo $fila['IdPrenda']; ?>" hidden="true">
```

Eso ya lo dejo para que lo arregles tu si lo necesitas realmente.

3. Vamos a poner a la escucha al nuevo div para que gestione los eventos `click` que va a recibir interiormente:

```
document.getElementById('padre').addEventListener("click", function(event){
```

4. Vamos a ejecutar el código de esta función solo si el elemento contiene la clase **btnCarrito**:

```
if (event.target.classList.contains('btnCarrito')) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

5. A continuación tenemos que volver a quitar el **getElementById** que aparece en la siguiente línea y referenciarlo de otro modo, pues también esta repetido, en este caso para el **txtAgregarCarId**, y lo podemos hacer así (porque antes hemos agregado el value= en el propio botón):

```
var parametros = "txtAgregarCarId=" + event.target.value;
```

6. Y el resto se queda igual, tan solo hay que agregar un cierre del nuevo condicional antes de cerrar la función así:

```
  var url = "../Consultas/VMostrarProductosClientes.php";

  xhr.open("POST", url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send(parametros);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
    {
        document.getElementById("Productos").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
  } 

}

});
```

Y diria que ya estamos. Prueba de realizar los cambios y ya nos diras si te ha funcionado.

Comment: Ya lo probé y si funciono, muchas gracias

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro por ti. Si esta respuesta soluciona tu problema deberías aceptarla para que la pregunta no quede pendiente eternamente y pueda ayudar a otros.  En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás como aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo. También léete el [tour] para aprender mejor el funcionamiento de este sitio, gracias.